# Gitlab CI/CD execute specific stages instead of all the stages

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have several stages in my `gitlab-ci.yml` file,

For example:

```
stages:
  - one
  - two
  - three
```

Is there possibility to run specified stages? In Makefile it's called "targets". I want in different cases execute different stages. For example:

```
if [ <condition 1> ]; then
  run all stages;
if [ <condition 2> ]; then
  run stage "one"; 
if [ <condition 3> ]; then
  run stages "two" and "three"; 
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it at the job level using [if](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#rulesif) rules.

Also, a [stage](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#stages) can contain only one job. So, create 3 jobs in your `.gitlab-ci.yml`, one per stage and configure rules like this (check the doc for more example) ex :

```
stages:
  - one
  - two
  - three

job_one:
  stage: one
  script: "echo Hello, stage one"
  rules: 
    - if: '$VAR == "string value"'

job_two:
  stage: two
  script: "echo Hello, stage two"
  rules: 
    - if: '$VAR == "string value"'

job_three:
  stage: three
  script: "echo Hello, stage three"
  rules: 
    - if: '$VAR == "string value"'
```